# add Array strings to an Object in a certain way

Tags: javascript, typescript

The object is for a changelog and is written this way:

```
{
      header: version,
      features: ["features"], // array with all the features (if there are any)
      bugfixes: ["bugfixes"], // same for the bugfixes
      other: ["other changes"] // there can be other types in the object
    };
```

This object needs to be filled with information from this Array:

```
["[3.0.0]", "Features", "changes done in file", "Bug Fixes", "fixed home"],
["[2.0.1]", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login"], 
["[2.0.0]","Features", "added home", "added footer", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login", "Breaking", "added a breaking change"]
```

There can be multiple features, multiple bugfixes, and other types of titles like `breaking`. I wanted to add these arrays into the object, making the final result look something like this for each version:

```
{
      header: "3.0.0",
      features: ["changes done in file"],
      bugfixes: ["bugfixes"],
    };
```

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. What have you tried and could you be more clear about your end result?

Comment: If you can clean this up to show how your example array would be represented (completely) in your result, then you might find it easier to get an answer. For instance, your example input shows "Features" and "Bug Fixes" for what is assumed to be version "3.0.0", but your example output shows two items under `other`, and none in `bugfixes`. You also mention "other types of titles like `breaking`", but no hint as to how that would map to the output.

Comment: i've tried filtering the strings by the first character being uppercase, creating an array for each title. but i couldn't find a way to fit the title's contents into their respective arrrays.  ´if (firstChar == firstChar.toUpperCase() && "a" <= firstChar && firstChar <= "z") {
        let arr = [];
        arr.push(this.input[i]);
        console.log(arr);
      }´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
If the changes are always recorded in lowercase, then you can avoid the Keys from my original answer:

```
let generateLog = changes => {
    let _key;
    return changes.reduce((log, entry, idx) => {
        if (idx === 0) {
            log.header = entry.slice(1, -1);
        } else {
            let charCode = entry.charCodeAt(0);
            let isKey = charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90;
            if (isKey) {
                let _value = entry.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase();
                if (!Array.isArray(log[_value])) {
                    log[_value] = [];
                }
                _key = _value;
            } else {
                log[_key].push(entry);           
            }
        }
        return log;
    }, {});
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y564xewm/2/

---

There are multiple ways in approaching this. I find maintaining a map of "keys" for your changelog object the easiest. How you approach that map is up to you (you can have 1:1 array mapping like: `stringKeys = [a, b, c]; objKeys = [x, y, z]`).

Once you've defined the keys, you'll need to look for those as you loop your array and apply the key to your changelog object. You'll need to maintain that key for the next array iteration, where you will push the value to the array.

When the next key is encountered, just repeat the previous.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y564xewm/

Solution:

```
// Register Change Log Keys
const CHANGE_LOG_KEYS = new Map();

// Key is response in array, Value is key assigned in object
// Adding a new key, like "Breaking" would be:
// CHANGE_LOG_KEYS.set('Breaking', 'breaking');
// Assuming response: [[x.x.x], 'Breaking', '...']

CHANGE_LOG_KEYS.set('Features', 'features');
CHANGE_LOG_KEYS.set('Bug Fixes', 'bugfixes');

let generateLog = changes => {
    let _key;
    return changes.reduce((log, entry, idx) => {
        if (idx === 0) {
            log.header = entry.slice(1, -1);
        } else {
            let value = CHANGE_LOG_KEYS.get(entry);
            if (value) {
                if (!Array.isArray(log[value])) {
                    log[value] = [];
                }
                _key = value;
            } else {
                log[_key].push(entry);
            }
        }
        return log;
    }, {});
}

let changes = [
    ["[3.0.0]", "Features", "changes done in file", "Bug Fixes", "fixed home"],
    ["[2.0.1]", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login"], 
    ["[2.0.0]","Features", "added home", "added footer", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login", "Breaking", "added a breaking change"]
];

changes.forEach(change => {
    console.log(generateLog(change));
});
```